# Why doesn't thermal radio emission from a DSN "hot dish" completely swamp the benefits of a cold LNA?

Tags: deep-space, radio-communication, deep-space-network, radio-telescope

The 70 meter DSN dishes are often used to receive the weakest signals, and so their receiver [LNAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-noise_amplifier) have cryogenic front-ends in an assembly that also contains a LHe refrigerator and vacuum system. If I understand correctly these are located in the "feed cones" pointed at the [Cassegrain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassegrain_reflector) secondary reflector which looks at the primary 70 meter mirror, and all of this sits outdoors in the desert air, hot during the day, cooler at night, but definitely warmer than 4K!

Why doesn't the blackbody radio emission of the hot dish just swamp the receiver, making the cooling the front-end irrelevant?

I'm not talking about the infrared radiation from the telescope. That is probably removed by managing line-of-sight within the cryogenic waveguide, or a low-temperature window or both. I'm talking about the circa 300K **radio emission** of the 70 meter primary and 8 meter secondary.

**below x2:** Screen shots from an extensive review in [Low-Noise Systems in the Deep Space Network](https://descanso.jpl.nasa.gov/monograph/series10/Reid_DESCANSO_sml-110804.pdf) NASA/JPL, Edited by Macgregor S. Reid, February 2008.

[image: Goldstone 70m cooled low noise amplifier]

[image: Goldstone 70m dish tricones]

Below are photos of one of the 70 meter [Deep Space Network](https://deepspace.jpl.nasa.gov/) telescopes for talking to deep space spacecraft. This one is in the Goldstone complex. From the relative sizes in the image, the secondary mirror is close to 8 meters in diameter. Considering the size and mass of the secondary (**those are stairs for humans on each leg**, and the red lines in the dish are "safe paths for walking") other, more advanced techniques to scan electronically have been developed, but the concept is the same.

[image: Goldstone 70m dish side view]

**above:** Photo credit [JPMajor](https://www.flickr.com/photos/lightsinthedark/13678357214/in/photostream/), creative commons CC BY-NC-SA 2.0.

[image: Goldstone 70m dish side view]

**above:** From [commons.wikimedia.org](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:DSN_Antenna_details.jpg).

Comment: I've borrowed the "outdoor images" form [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/286062/102305).

Comment: This is essentially a question about radio astronomy; there might be more people qualified to answer on Astronomy.

Comment: @Phiteros it is a question about managing spacecraft. It is not about radio astronomy. I would have asked about an astronomical object, not a method to retrieve data from the Voyagers or New Horizons. This cooled LNA and dish system have been designed and optimized *by NASA* specifically to work in certain relatively narrow communications bands. This is NASA spacecraft communications hardware, not an instrument to image hydrogen emission in the intergalactic void or radio jets around neutron stars or the CMB. *I still have five unanswered radio astronomy questions there, don't need one more!*

Comment: @Phiteros [1](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/19772/7982), [2](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/18791/7982), [3](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/16240/7982), [4](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/16621/7982), [5](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/18052/7982) although I have since found the answer to one of them and should post it. Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: I'm not saying that it's not applicable to spacecraft.  It certainly isn't off-topic here.  But what you're essentially asking is "Why don't the reflectors contribute to the antenna temperature?", which is also a consideration for radio astronomy.

Comment: @Phiteros My question is "completely swamp", not "contribute". I'm asking exactly what I'm asking, not "essentially" something else. The answer may include considerations related to the narrow bandwidth, or particular frequencies here. Just because they may both be dish-shaped does not necessarily mean that a radio telescope and a communications link are identical at the systems level. There could be some special engineered-emissivity layer under the white paint appropriate for X-band for example. Let's see if we can find out instead of presupposing.

Comment: Whether you're looking at a spacecraft or a high-redshift quasar, you're looking at a weak source.

Comment: You might be interested in the video about the receiver technology of this receiver on youtube on the eevdiscover channel

Comment: @uhoh: it even seems to be a three part thing, a voyager 2 contact howto ;) https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCkGvUEt8iQLmq3aJIMjT2qQ/videos

Comment: @PlasmaHH all three videos of the monologue/walking tour are really interesting! Listening closely, there are many gems here, and some really useful insight. Thanks!

Comment: I had a very similar question at the electronics stack exchange. It uses slightly different vocabulary which might be interesting: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/279164/johnson-nyquist-noise-contribution-antenna-noise-temperatures

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Planck → Rayleigh-Jeans:

> I'm not talking about the infrared radiation from the telescope. That is probably removed by managing line-of-sight within the cryogenic waveguide, or a low-temperature window or both. I'm talking about the circa 300K radio emission of the 70 meter primary and 8 meter secondary.

The key to answering this question is to have some insight into the misconceptions of the OP (me!). The OP's (i.e. *my*) thinking was that the 300K radio emission of the primary and secondary would also somehow scale as $T^4$ and therefore produce *of order ten million times stronger radio signal* than the 4K cooled receiver.

But while the total power radiated by a blackbody scales as $T^4$, the radiated power has *temperature-dependent shape* that must be considered. If you look at the *radio portion* of the [Plank distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law) for things that are significantly hotter than 4K, the intensity per unit bandwidth does not increase as  $T^4$, but *only linearly with temperature.* So very roughly the "hot dish" is only outshining the receiver by roughly 300/4 or about 75 times, not ten million times. This linear dependence for things much hotter than the characteristic temperature of the bandwidth under consideration is called the [Rayleigh-Jeans law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh%E2%80%93Jeans_law), and looks like

$$B_{\nu}(T) = \frac{2 \nu^2}{c^2} k_B T$$

where $B_{\nu}(T)$ is [spectral radiance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiance); the the power emitted per unit emitting area, per steradian, per unit wavelength or in this case *per unit frequency* $\nu$.

**edit:** Incidentally, it is exactly this relationship that allows us to "add temperatures" as a way of adding noise power from different sources to get a noise figure, as illustrated for example in @Phiteros' [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/21270/12102).

Plotted on a log-log graph, you can see that the peak heights increase three times faster than the straight-line low-frequency segments do, showing the $T^3$ dependence of the spectral density peak height versus the linear behavior in the Rayleigh-Jeans regime. If you integrated the total area under the curve, you'd get the $T^4$ dependence of the total power radiated by a blackbody.

**below:** From New Jersey Institute of Technology's Dr. Dale Gary's nicely-written Physics 728 Radio Astronomy; [Lecture #1](https://web.njit.edu/~gary/728/Lecture1.html) notes:

[image]

---

### Emissivity:

So using "science" and Wikipedia, we've brought of order ten million down to a measly 75. The *second* and much smaller factor for the OP's (my) dilemma, which brings this down to parity is the *emissivity of metal* at radio frequency, as mentioned in @pericynthion's [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/21271/12102). In its *entirety:*

> Because the dish isn't a black body. At RF it has a very low emissivity, hence the name "reflector".

[Kirchov's Law of Thermal Radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_law_of_thermal_radiation) can be stated as:

> For an arbitrary body emitting and absorbing thermal radiation in thermodynamic equilibrium, the emissivity is equal to the absorptivity.

Since the metal dishes (primary and secondary) are thick enough so that no RF is transmitted, we can say that the sum of reflectivity and absorbtivity will equal unity. Since we know the metal of the dish and any overlying paint have been carefully chosen and optimized to be the best possible reflector for the very weak signals from space, the absorptivity must be very very low, and we can guess it might be of the order of a percent or so.

That can pull the remaining factor of 75 down to unity or below, so that the hot dish which was originally and incorrectly *thought* to be ten million times stronger than the thermal noise of the amplifier, is now down (roughly) to parity with it.

Answer (score 12):

When discussing radio antennae, radio astronomers usually describe things in terms of temperatures.  We can convert between power and temperature simply by multiplying (or dividing) by Boltzmann's Constant: $P=k_BT$.  We define the antenna's **System Temperature**, $T_{sys}$, as the sum of all the temperature contributing factors.

The most important contributor to $T_{sys}$ is the source temperature, $T_{A}$.  Sometimes this temperature is just the temperature of a blackbody, but for non-thermal sources we use brightness temperature:

$$
T_b=\frac{S_\nu \lambda^2}{2k_B\theta_s^2}
$$

where $S_\nu$ is the source flux density, $\lambda$ is the wavelength, and $\theta_s^2$ is the angular size of the object.  In the case of a spacecraft, $\theta_s^2$ would be the angular size of the spacecraft's [antenna beam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_antenna#Beamwidth): $\theta=k\frac{\lambda}{d}$ where $k$ is a coefficient dependent on the geometry of the dish.

Other sources of temperature come from the spillover from the ground, ambient sky temperature, and the antenna itself.  So how do we get rid of those contributions?  The answer: calibration.

When we observe a source, be it a spacecraft or a quasar, in order to determine the amplitude of the actual signal we are receiving, we calibrate by looking at a source of known flux density.  Usually this is done in radio astronomy by first observing a bright point source near to our target.  Some telescopes utilize a calibrator device that emits a known flux.  For a spacecraft, it is probably even simpler: the engineers will know the power the signal is being transmitted with, the beam size, and the source distance.  From that they can easily calculate the brightness temperature.  Once we know what kind of flux we should be getting from our source, we can easily subtract away the unwanted temperature components.  They will still add some noise to our signal, as our calibrations can never be perfect.  However, they will not completely swamp our signal.

Alternatively, instead of looking at an absolute flux calibrator, if you're looking at a point-source (like a spacecraft), you can simply calibrate by pointing your beam off-source.  By assuming that your noise is gaussian in nature, it will be the same both on-source and slightly off it.  You can rapidly switch between the beams, and subtract your off-source beam from your on-source beam.  This will leave you with the signal from your source itself.  This is known as [Dicke Switching](http://www.cv.nrao.edu/course/astr534/Radiometers.html).

Now, why do we cool the receivers so much?  The answer is that we are seeking to decrease the receiver temperature, $T_{R}$.  The antenna's receiver contains amplifiers to gain up the signal.  The receiver temperature is given by:
$$
T_R=T_{G,1}+\frac{T_{G,2}}{G_1}+\frac{T_{G,3}}{G_1G_2}+...
$$
where $T_{G,n}$ is the temperature of the nth amplifier and $G_n$ is the gain of the nth amplifier.  As long as you are gaining your signal up by a few orders of magnitude at each step, each successive amplifier contributes practically nothing to the overall receiver temperature.  Therefore, your biggest contribution is the first amplifier.  If we were to leave the receiver out in the open, this would add a whopping 300 K to our signal, a contribution that we cannot simply calibrate away.  However, by cooling it to ~4 K, you eliminate the majority of the noise that would come from your receiver.  As the above website notes, when using Dicke switching, you end up doubling your receiver temperature, which is another reason they seek to cool the receivers by such a great amount.

Source: *Tools of Radio Astronomy* by Wilson, Rohlfs, and Huttemeister, 5th ed.

Comment: I do not see anything that answers my question here. Where is the dish and secondary reflector temperature referred to here? The first two words of my question are "Why doesn't..." so I'm *looking for the why*.

Comment: I apologize if I wasn't clear.  The dish and reflector temperatures are included as the antenna temperature.

Comment: Which symbol in the equations stands for antenna temperature? Which equation shows that a 300K antenna temperature does not overwhelm an effort to cool the LNA to 4K? I don't see the proof here.

Comment: I don't understand your question here.  Basically, to get the system temperature, you sum all of the temperature components.  The LNA is a part of the receiver temperature.  Calibrating electronics is tricky, but by cooling it is simple.  The antenna temperature is independent of the receiver temperature and is subtracted out from the system temperature via calibration procedures which happen during signal analysis.  Basically, we'd like to cool the entire antenna, but we can't.  We cool what we can, and we use calibration to take care of the rest.

Comment: You would "subtract out a temperature" for a radiometer, not for a data communications link. I think you are applying radiometry calibration concepts here which don't really apply.

Comment: I think the same principle does still apply, actually.  You're looking for a weak signal source, so you calibrate.  This is all besides the fact that if we treat the antenna as a blackbody, it will radiate primarily in the infrared, not in the radio.

Comment: How can you "calibrate" to cancel random noise? If this were possible, why doesn't your car radio have a "calibrate" button which makes a distant radio station come in clearly? If you are trying to determine the power being received from that distant radio station, sure you can calibrate for the noise power and adjust for that when measuring power received by the antenna. But as for _actually removing the noise_, I don't see how that's possible.

Comment: @PhilFrost It's rather simple:  The noise contributions from both the sky and the antenna itself are gaussian in nature.  What's more, they will be the same both on-source and off.  So you form two beams: one on-source and one off-source.  The temperature contribution from your off-source beam is noise.  You subtract this noise from your on-source signal.  You're still left with a very small amount of residual noise, but that is to be expected in any case.  You can't just calibrate a car antenna in this way because a car antenna is just a dipole, it doesn't beam-form and doesn't point.

Comment: @uhoh I just asked my radio astronomy professor about this.  He said that he knew the person who was the head of the DSN for a while, and this person was also a radio astronomer.  The same techniques you use in radio astronomy are applied to getting signals from space probes.  Space probe signals are just narrow-band weak point sources.

Comment: But the noise _is not the same on source and off source_. You just said it yourself: the noise is random. It can't be the same because that's the definition of random. What you _can_ measure is the noise power, and you can express that as a noise temperature if you want. If you want to measure the luminosity of a source that's great, but if you are trying to decode a signal with information which has been corrupted by noise, knowing the power of that noise doesn't help at all.

Comment: @PhilFrost When we say that the noise is 'random', we mean that there are tiny, random fluctuations in it.  HOWEVER, these fluctuations should be the same wherever we look.  The point of this question is how we get rid of the signal contributions from the telescope and sky.  When we end up with our final signal, we still have some noise in it, from these tiny fluctuations.  However, via this calibration, we can subtract out the temperature contributions from the sky and antenna.  We still get that small noise, which we call "thermal noise".

Comment: @Phiteros Noise samples coming from two different regions of the sky are independent, so if you subtract them you actually increase the background noise by sqrt(2).

Comment: @gosnold Firstly, by looking at two pieces of sky that are very close to each other, we can approximate them as having similar noise.  Secondly, what we're more concerned with than the thermal noise is subtracting out the signal from the sky itself - the temperature contribution.  Think of it as us having a large signal with a little noise on top.  We don't care too much about the noise, but we want to subtract away the large signal, to leave us with just the source signal.

Answer (score 12):

Because the dish isn't a black body. At RF it has a very low emissivity, hence the name "reflector".

Comment: Numbers please, and a reference, so we can believe it. Also, I see white paint everywhere btw. Let's build a good answer for future readers. How low is "very low"? What would the "effective temperature" contribution be of a 300K dish with an emissivity of $\epsilon_{dish}$, where $\epsilon_{dish}$ is the "very low" emissivity that you supply in the answer? 150K? 50K? The front end could potentially be as cold as 4K. At least ballpark numbers would help demonstrate the principle and make it believable that a "hot dish" isn't really so hot after all!

Comment: White paint is transparent to RF. Emissivity is low enough that the antenna noise contribution from its self temperature is negligible - it's dominated by the ground temperature from the portion of the sidelobes that see the earth.  Typically single-digit Kelvins noise temp for a well-designed reflector at moderate to high elevation angles.

Comment: Please be less rude. You don't get to dictate how I answer. Write your own if you want.

Comment: Invoking transparency does not help by itself. [This hot glass](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/254099/83380) is transparent to visible wavelengths but can simultaneously glow quite brightly at visible wavelengths!

Comment: This is more of a comment than a proper stackexchange answer. Handwaving arguments (as in the "skipped-step" definition used by people running out of chalk at a blackboard) are great among friends and to save time, but for a helpful stackexchange answer it's best to back up quantitative statements of something being large or small with either some math or a supporting link. Without that, future readers have no way to verify the validity of the answer, and stackexchange is all about good answers.

Comment: This has a table of metal emissivities, alumium can go as low as 0.04: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=p8EO7N8qDNcC&pg=PA151&lpg=PA151&dq=emissivity+metal+microwave&source=bl&ots=JM7W5zaCGL&sig=3XfHfuFWRYieeb_BVagBCh4Yk8c&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=emissivity%20metal%20microwave&f=false

Comment: @gosnold thanks! The book's title suggest microwaves, but I couldn't find from the table if those are microwave or infrared emissivities. Also notable that even a thin coating might be enough - it wouldn't have to be solid gold luckily. With a 300K reflector and a 4K front-end, even 0.04 might be rather high though.

Comment: @ right, it could be IR. Found this paper (Emissivity measurements of reflective surfaces at near-millimeter wavelengths, https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/edab/25070c0a438a7ddbbbf1b2c7460b9be7b5c0.pdf) that says emisiivity of aluminium is 3.10-3 at 1.17mm, so it adds 1K of noise temperature.

Comment: @gosnold don't forget the "uhoh" after the "(at)" sign. This is a great reference, thanks!  I'm stuck not knowing how to do the math even behind this sentence in the introduction: "*The thermal emission from a simple 300 K mirror surface with an emissivity $\epsilon=2.5\times10^{-3}$ is, for example, 10 times brighter than the astrophysical sky at $\lambda=1mm$*."

Comment: @uhoh That means emissivity * 300k> 1/10* whatever the sky temperature is at 1mm (you cannot calculate that one simply, but there are charts of sky temps vs frequency in many books)

Comment: @gosnold the "astrophysical sky" is presumably 2.73K, no? Oh, maybe not, there's atmospheric water. OK I don't care about *simply*, I just care about calculate :)  so maybe I have to ask a separate question about this. Hope to hit the library this weekend first.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main reason can be viewed two ways:

1. Although faint, the signal is also highly directional, coming from a
   single point in the sky, so it's brightness temperature is actually
   quite high. So long as the telescope is big enough to focus in on a
   very small patch of sky, the signal is louder than the noise.
2. The thermal noise from the different parts of the dish has a random phase, so when it all adds together at the receiver, it largely cancels out.

These are really the same reason, in two guises, since the reason mirrors work as they do can be seen to be to do with all the reflected signals arriving in phase.

Noise from the receiver comes in **after** the telescope has selected for signals from a particular direction, so it doesn't get the benefit of this effect and must be reduced by other means (like cooling the antenna).

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem of not seeing the forest because of the trees.
Of course, any signal can be swamped by noise of the most diverse origins, including the thermal component of the antenna structure.
The trick is to dimension everything from the beginning in order to reach a suitable signal to noise ratio for the intended communication purpose. In other words, in relationship to the incident signal's power density, frequency, bandwidth and modulation there are minimal requirements on the construction of the antenna.
As pertaining to the thermal noise of the metal, (well noted above) it's maximum is far from radio bands and is random as regarding amplitude and polarization. That is, the metal structure at 300K is not seen by the antenna feed as a noise source of 300K equivalent temperature. Even if it would have been, the important thing is the antenna being big enough and having the shape and stability (i.e. gain) necessary to ensure the required signal to noise ratio.
The temperature of the first LNA is much more important in terms of noise (or equivalent noise temperature - also well noted above) because it "fixates" the global performance of the receiving system.